# Select all rows that contain the first x unique values in another column in Pandas [Python]

Tags: pandas, unique

```
selected =df['col2'].unique().iloc[1:5]
apples = df[df['col2'].isin([selected])]
print(df)
```

Here is my pseudocode for what I'm trying to accomplish. I just want to get the first five unique values in column 2, and then subset the whole dataframe based on those values. I get this error on the first line:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Comment: `df['col2'].unique()[:5]`?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is your array slicing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col2":np.random.randint(1,50,100)})
df[df["col2"].isin(df['col2'].unique()[:5])]
```

### output

|  | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 27 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 20 | 13 |
| 27 | 1 |
| 31 | 4 |
| 35 | 4 |
| 42 | 13 |
| 43 | 27 |
| 48 | 3 |
| 59 | 4 |
| 60 | 4 |
| 67 | 4 |
| 90 | 3 |
| 95 | 4 |
| 96 | 4 |
| 98 | 13 |